# what is the meaning of "high quarter"? and What is the meaning of "wrote in favor of the persecuted sect?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Antiochus, his representative at the
Court of Arcadius, openly wrote in favor of the persecuted sect; and the
encouragement received from this high quarter rapidly increased the
number of professing Christians in the Persian territories.

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm

Comment: There, quarter means a high place or a high authority.  It seems to refer to the court which received his writing about the Christians favorably. It means he wrote texts, like, on papyri which showed he was pro the Christian sect.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for your good help. can you help me about second question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Quarter" has a meaning of "division of a town".  For example you will sometimes hear "the Latin quarter". More generally "quarter" can mean "section of society" (though this use is dated and rare).  You might say

> There is concern from many quarters about the proposed business restructuring.

The Court of (the Eastern Roman Emperor) Arcadius was a very high ranking part of society. This court is the "High quarter".

The "persecuted sect" is the Christian community, and Antiochus wrote letters that were in favour of the Christians. He wrote these letters openly. That means he signed his name on the letters, instead of writing them secretly with no signature.